# If a problem A ≤p B, then that B ≤p A, prove or disprove

Tags: reductions, discrete-mathematics

I think the intuition is to disprove this by counter example, but what are 2 specific well known problems I can use as counter example?

Comment: Can you please list as least one problem that you do know?

Comment: I think I can use 1 SAT vs 3 SAT, 1 SAT can reduce to 3 SAT by setting all clauses to contain only x and not x, but 3 SAT can't reduce to 1 SAT.